# Can't connect to server on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

ı try conncet my sql database on amazon aws

```
mysql -h database-2.csgofm1hhtui.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u ismail -p
```

But i recieve this exception

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on 'database-2.csgofm1hhtui.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two inbound rules for the database to work, one for your website and the other to connect to it through SSH/a database client (e.g. Dbeaver). (Note : My website is hosted on EC2). The following rules work for me.

NOTE: You may need to make the database "Publicly Available".
[image]

Comment: I still don't get why checking "Publicly Available" is of any use, when only manually adding this inbound rule to the security group opens up the MySQL server (take the domain name + port 3306 into the browser URL and see if it responds with some scrambled characters +`Got packets out of order` msg). What does the check "Publicly Available" do anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question, but have you opened inbound Security Group rules?

This error is a result of the inbound connection rule set on your DB instance.

In AWS RDS console, under 'Databases', click on the 'DB Identifier' of your RDS instance. Then in the 'Security group rules' section, click on 'Inbound' type security group and edit the inbound rule to allow appropriate inbound connections.

IF you are trying to connect from an EC2 instance, then the Inbound connection can be the security group of your EC2 instance on port 3306.

See point 4 in the following link :
[Create a VPC security group for a private DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateVPC.html#CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateVPC.SecurityGroupDB)

If its not Security Group, then it could be a route table issue.

[AWS Knowledge Center - How do I resolve problems when connecting to my Amazon RDS DB instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know the static IP address that you want to allow access. This could be the IP address of a specific computer or network device.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).